# The column positioning breaks in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

A picture is worth a thousand words so...

Structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-center column-fix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src.... />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="category-link">
                    <a href...></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

Output:

[image: Bootstrap column positioning]

Basically, when a column is higher than the others, it causes the order to break. I understand this is how floats work, but I need a nice and clean solution for this. At the moment, this is my workaround:

```
.column-fix {
    float: none !important; 
    display: inline-block !important; 
    margin: 0 -0.125em !important; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

And this is the output I get with the fix:

[image]

Is there a nice solution that will override all columns in all widths without setting a custom class to every element? I want the bootstrap col-* classes to behave like inline-blocks instead of floats.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is in a little more detail, as well as what you wan't it to do? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated my question with another screenshot.